# VMware Linux LAMP server internet

Tags: linux, vmware, lamp

I am installing Ubuntu server 12.04 in a VM for a LAMP server. How should i configure the network for the VM so I can access the webpages hosted on it from the host pc and so that the VM still has internet access, to download more packages?

thanks

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you are using VMware workstation or Fusion, if so, there are 3 way for network config.

1. NAT mode (host PC and Internet)
2. Host only (host PC)
3. Bridged mode (host PC and Internet??)

Obviously, you want VM accessable from host and also own Internet access, the the best choice for you is NAT mode. Bridge maybe work for you, but it denpend whether you have extra valid Internet IP to grant. 
There is a link for you reference (http://communities.vmware.com/docs/DOC-2527). It is about fusion, but workstation is almost the same thing.

Hope above helpful for you.